# Python - How to alter variable in a module imported as "from module import *"

Tags: python

"""Making a better version of my IF(Interactive Fiction) module so you can just create a module that imports it and you can start adding crap
Three things- Well four if you count the DEBUG variable-
The variables PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_LOCATION, and PLAYER_INVENTORY. In the base they are "Luke", None, and list
The adventure content module uses "from mask_IF import *", changing any of those variables makes it in the current namespace- it doesn't alter the imported ones.
And due to *, I can't mask_IF.VARIABLE = value either.

I would like to keep my "from mask_IF import *", but at the same time I have these variables which should be defined with every separate adventure module and are used in the main module. """

====
In the main module:

```
PLAYER_NAME = "Luke"
...
class ActionHelp(Action):
    def ActionHandle(self, Object1, Object2):
        print "No help for you, " + PLAYER_NAME + "!"
```

In the adventure module:

```
from mask_IF import *
Text("Your name is normally " + PLAYER_NAME)
...
PLAYER_NAME = "Adventure_Tester #001"
Text("But today you are " + PLAYER_NAME)
```

====
Your name is normally Luke
But today you are Adventure_Tester #001

> help
>   No help for you, Luke!
>   The command is help
>   The Object1 is NOT GIVEN
>   The Object2 is NOT GIVEN

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this, for the reason you have given. It can be simulated by creating an object with the appropriate attributes, but then you may as well not import * to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do it. the "from mask_IF import *" is creating a new variable named PLAYER_NAME in your current module, which happens to point to the same underlying data to begin with. It is *not* an alias for the variable in the mask_IF module. When you try to assign something else to PLAYER_NAME, you're telling the local variable to point to something new, which has no effect at all on what the mask_IF variable points to.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use an object like StrObj instead of strings, then you would be dealing with a mutable type reference that could have a value updated from anywhere.  The only difference in your code would be in setting it with a call to `Set()` rather than `= '...'`.

```
class StrObj(object):
    def __init__(self, value=''):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return other + self.value
    def Set(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Assuming that in `mask_IF.py`, `PLAYER_NAME = StrObj('Some Name')`...

```
from mask_IF import *
Text("Your name is normally " + PLAYER_NAME)
...
PLAYER_NAME.Set("Adventure_Tester #001")
Text("But today you are " + PLAYER_NAME)
```

**All that being said...**

I think you would be better off defining a `Player` object with properties for `NAME`, etc... and just using that instead.  I recommend using `import *` sparsely.